# Is a way to divide dependenty from support design library to smaller peaces?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In gardle dependencies I have such a line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

I want split in parts which I'm using in fact. So I search something like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design-coordinatorlayout:23.1.1'
```

or so.
Is a such possibility?

Answer (score 0):

There is no artifactId like `design-foobar`. So you can't split

Check `maven-metadata.xml` of Support Library's repository in sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml

By the way, `constraint-layout` is not part of design support library.
It is independent.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
```

see: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor